# Signal/Slot help-- setting a signal to a slot outside of the current class

Tags: pyqt, signals-slots

I'm trying to populate a table (present in the main window) from a slider that's located in a widget in a separate class.  I can't seem to get it to work...what's the best way to go about doing this?
Here's my current code:

```py
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,filename,parent=None):
        super(Widget,self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(900,900)
        self.layout=QVBoxLayout(self)


        frame=Frame(filename)
        self.image=pg.ImageView()
        self.image.setImage(frame.data)
        self.image.setCurrentIndex(0)

        fileheader=FileHeader(filename)
        self.slider=QSlider(self)
        self.slider.setOrientation(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.slider.setMinimum(1)
        self.slider.setMaximum(fileheader.numframes)
        self.slider.sliderMoved.connect(self.sliderMoved)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.image)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.slider)


    def sliderMoved(self,val):
        print "slider moved to:", val
        fileheader=FileHeader(filename)
        idx=val
        frame=fileheader.frameAtIndex(idx)
        self.image.setImage(frame.data)



class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, filename, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(parent)

        self.initUI(filename)

    def initUI(self,filename):
        self.filetable=QTableWidget()

        self.frametable=QTableWidget()

        self.imageBrowser=Widget(filename)
        self.imagesplitter=QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.tablesplitter=QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.imagesplitter.addWidget(self.imageBrowser)
        self.tablesplitter.addWidget(self.imagesplitter)
        self.tablesplitter.addWidget(self.filetable)
        self.tablesplitter.addWidget(self.frametable)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tablesplitter)

        exitAction=QAction(QIcon('exit.png'),'&Exit',self)
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)

        openAction=QAction(QIcon('open.png'),'&Open',self)
        openAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')


        menubar=self.menuBar()
        fileMenu=menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(openAction)

        self.fileheader=FileHeader(filename)
        self.connect(self.frametable,  
                     SIGNAL("Widget.sliderMoved(idx)"),
                     self.fileheader.frameAtIndex(idx))
        self.frameheader=self.fileheader.frameAtIndex(0)
        self.populate()


    def populate(self):
        self.filetable.setRowCount(len(self.fileheader.fileheader_fields))
        self.filetable.setColumnCount(2)
        self.filetable.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['File Header','value'])
        for i,field in enumerate(self.fileheader.fileheader_fields):
            name=QTableWidgetItem(field)
            value=QTableWidgetItem(unicode(getattr(self.fileheader,field)))
            self.filetable.setItem(i,0,name)
            self.filetable.setItem(i,1,value)

        self.frametable.setRowCount(len(self.frameheader.frameheader_fields))
        self.frametable.setColumnCount(2)
        self.frametable.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Frame Header','Value'])
        for i,fields in enumerate(self.frameheader.frameheader_fields):
            Name=QTableWidgetItem(fields)
            Value=QTableWidgetItem(unicode(getattr(self.frameheader,fields)))
            self.frametable.setItem(i,0,Name)
            self.frametable.setItem(i,1,Value)
```

I know the "connect" is wrong-- I'm very new to PyQt and Python in general, so I'm not quite sure where to start.

Comment: Actually, that `connect` looks fine. What's not working?

Comment: The connect in the Widget class works beautifully.  I need to connect the same slider to a table in the MainWindow class... I fixed a bit of the code, but I'm still getting "global name idx (the index number I'm hoping to set in the SliderMoved function) is not defined"

Comment: Ah, I see the problematic `connect` now. One more question though, shouldn't `self.frametable=QTableWidget()` be `self.frametable=Widget()`? The way you wrote that `connect` suggests latter. With that correction, it still wouldn't be correct, but I wanted to double-check. (By the way, it'll be better if you include that error with full traceback in the question. For completeness sake.)

Comment: The Widget() is the image browser and slider...the frame header table I wrote into the main window.  Should I put that in the Widget() instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `self.imageBrowser` is your Widget class, it will have the slider attribute which has the sliderMoved signal. You just need a few more dots.

```
self.imageBrowser.slider.sliderMoved.connect(self.fileheader.frameAtIndex)
```

The way you have it organized is correct though. Your main window composes your custom widgets and binds the connections together.

Though because you have a data source, and also a QTableWidget that will need to be updated, you probably need to wrap the steps up into a little method:

```py
def initUI(self,filename):
    ...
    self.imageBrowser.slider.sliderMoved.connect(self._handle_slider_moved)
    # initialize it the first time during the window set up
    self._handle_slider_moved(0)

def _handle_slider_moved(self, val):
    # update the data source
    self.fileheader.frameAtIndex(val)
    # update the second data source 
    self.frameheader=self.fileheader.frameAtIndex(0)
    # now refresh the tables
    self.populate()
```

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying.  I'm trying to connect the slider to the frame header table as well, to populate the frame header table with the frame at the index set by the slider... is this how I would do that?  Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean `self.frametable`? If so, that is just a normal `QTableWidget`. What are you trying to connect to on that object?

Comment: So the Widget() class is an image view and a slider below it.  The main window is split into thirds with the image browser, the frame header table, and the file header table.  When you move the slider, it changes the image, and I'd like it to change the frame table as well (populate with attributes of that frame).  I'm running in circles with this for some reason *headdesk*   And hello, it's you!